# is there a way which can tell me if a message in whatsapp was tagged (or replying to)

Tags: python, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-autopilot

CONTEXT:
Im trying to make a reminder system on whatsapp (TWILIO AUTOPILOT)

and to change state of task from incomplete to complete i thought it would be easy if user tags or replies to a particular reminder with done.

QUESTION:
If a user tags or replies to a message, is there a way i can retrieve information about that message, example the text in contained

IMAGE:

[image: Reply img 1]

[image: reply image two]

output needed in this case:
"Todays List: ... etc etc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid that information is not currently available in the Twilio API for WhatsApp. You can see [the extra parameters that you receive in the webhook for a WhatsApp message here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request#whatsapp-specific-parameters), including parameters like `ProfileName`, `WaId`, `Forwarded`, `FrequentlyForwarded` and `ButtonText`, but nothing to do with replied to messages.

Comment: i went through this doc! but thank you anyway. wanted to make sure i didnt overlook anything! :D

Comment: update!
The message that is being replied to can be fetched but only through official whatsapp API (called context of the message) returns a whatsapp message ID

Comment: @AkshayB do you know if we can use the whatsapp api when using twilio?

Comment: @AmirBar yes we can use the whatsapp api in a sandbox version. But only certain features with limitation until you have a verified Facebook business account

Comment: @AkshayB my business is verified, but right now I am sending through twilio, so I can start using the cloud api directly?

Comment: Yes! Follow these steps and you can start using yourapi end points according to docs https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/connect-number-business-profile